# get pdiffer working in ubuntu

Tags: python, c, interface

I am trying to use pdiffer in ubuntu.
It is a python interface to the PerceptualDiff tool.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdiffer

I installed pdiffer using pip (after installing pip)

I installed cmake

I installed freeimage (sudo apt-get install libfreeimage-dev)

I built PerceptualDiff following the read me file.

As far as I know, everything is setup (there were no errors).
Under Home/Documents I have my two images and a folder called pdiff that has the compiled perceptualdiff file in it.

I used the python interpreter in a terminal window

from pdiffer import PDiffer

```
pdiff = PDiffer(bin='/home/username/Documents/pdiff/perceptualdiff')
result = pdiff('image1.png', 'image2.png')
```

no errors until the last command

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'PDiffer' object is not callable
```

This is the first time I've tried to use a python interface for a C module. If you could tell me what I'm doing wrong (or let me know what other information I need to include), I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation lacks a basic explanation.

Let's have a look first at your error. You create an instance of the `PDiffer` class and then trie to call that instance again. See this very simplified example with the same error:

```
>>> class PDiffer:
...   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...     pass
... 
>>> pdiff = PDiffer(bin="/path/to/bin")
>>> pdiff("image1.png", "image2.png")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'PDiffer' object is not callable
```

That said, the documentation gives 2 options to use pdiff.
Create an instance of `PDiff` and give it a custom path to the binary or use the helper function `pdiff`. Giving them the same variable name and using them in the same code block is just very confusing. It's either one OR the other.

I had to look at the source to see what's going on. You should use the `pdiff` method of the `PDiff` class instead. The second example is a shortcut to this method with the custom binary path.

So a working example would be:

```
from pdiffer import PDiffer
pdiff = PDiffer(bin='/home/username/Documents/pdiff/perceptualdiff')
result = pdiff.pdiff('image1.png', 'image2.png')
```